# How can I get the language of a page from graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is there a way to check the language of a page?  For example graph.facebook.com/LaMenteEsMaravillosa is clearly a french page.  Is there  way to get "fr" or something from Facebook to recognize that this is not in english?

Answer (score 0):

All the fields you can get from a Page are in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

There is no language field, but it would not make any sense anyway. You can´t select a language for a Page, you can write stuff in any language on it.

Comment: Yea, this is what I figured, I just wanted to double check